# Insert layout from resources or create in code?

Tags: java, android, layout, layout-inflater

I want to put in existing scrolled `LinearLayout(*1)` another `Layouts(*2)`. I am a bit confused which way to go.

```
First one:
```

To define in xml `Layout(*2)` and load it from resources to application, set its child elements(text/edit/icon views) values (unique_id/text) and then put it in scrolled `Layout(*1`).

```
Second one:
```

Build `Layout(*2)` from scratch in code and then insert it in `LinearLayout(*1)`.

I know the general rule is to define layout in xml. But this is litle different approach. What If we consider removing this elements. I mean if every inserted layout is visible by program as a separate object ?

Thanks for clarify.

EDIT:
When I follow second way, it is easy to set values and problematic to set attributes but it actually works. Just want to know if there is sense to do this first way.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the first approach, you have to `inflate` the layout resource using the `LayoutInflater`, you can get it in your activity calling the method `getLayoutInflater()`. Then you can add the `View` you are getting this way by calling

`yourView.addView(newView)`

**EDIT**

Both ways are good, it's up to you to choose which one. Generally I would use the first approach, to keep the code cleaner from the set up of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this :-

```
setContentView(ll);

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.common_layout)
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setText("sample text");
ll.addView(tv);
```

It might be help.